# Caliburn Micro disable buttons which have no Property?

Tags: c#, button, caliburn.micro

At the moment i'm working with Caliburn Micro. But i got to a problem which i don't know how to solve.

The problem is i want to disable Buttons, but every website has only a solution with propertys. the functions of my buttons for example just start a thread to establish a connection over tcp with Netmq. So i don't know how i'll be able to disable them. Searched a lot through google but didn't find anything helpful.

Example of a button function

```
public void startPubButton()
    {
        Thread entryThread = new Thread(startPublisher);
        entryThread.IsBackground = true;
        entryThread.Start();
    }
```

is there maybe a possibility to enable the Buttons only when the thread runs ?

Answer (score 1):

That is the one premise behind CM wiring up by convention all you have to do is provide a CanstartPubButton Boolean property run a code check to see if you can enable or disable button according to the logic with that `guard` property.  Call with `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanstartPubButton);` in some fashion to do what you want.  The logic with in the property (get only needed) is up to you.  one other thing I will drop on you is a thread presently in the GitHub discussions on the repository itself.  Might help and it might not

https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/422

Comment: is there a shorter way than this ?

`private bool _sendMes = false;
        public bool SendMes
        {
            get { return _sendMes; }
            set
            {
                _sendMes = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SendMes);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSendMesButton);
            }
        }

        public bool CanSendMesButton
        {
            get { return SendMes; }
        }`